# iAd not loading ads xcode7

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad, swift2

I've used the same code on all my apps to display iAd ads, but after downloading xcode 7 and converting my code to swift2, ads don't appear anymore on my device or on the xcode simulator. Does anyone know what changes need to be made?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var adBanner: ADBannerView? = ADBannerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        adBanner?.delegate = self

        adBanner?.hidden = true

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true     

    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        adBanner?.hidden = true

    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        adBanner?.hidden = false

    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return willLeave
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered iAd network to be down at the very moment?
Always keep a copy of Apples own iAd Suite at hand:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Introduction/Intro.html

If their own dont't load, yours won't load either.

Right now I'm getting this self explanatory error message:

```
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two approaches. There are two ways of displaying iAd banners. First one, just let iAd know that you want do show banners on your view controller and let iAd do the rest. This is done by calling the following method:

```
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

Second approach is to load the banner first and then add it manually to your view. To do that, you first initialise the banner with the desired type and set its delegate:

```
var adBanner: ADBannerView? = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)
adBanner?.delegate = self
```

Then, when the banner is loaded, we have to add it to a view, for example:

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.view.addSubview(banner)
}
```

There is no need to change the `hidden` property before the banner i added to superview.

Comment: What I've used has always worked for me, and I'm sure using the code you provided worked as well. I've tried it your way to see if it would change anything but no luck.

Comment: Try setting frame to your banner.